# $card-md-margin-left not working properly in variables.scss

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm looking for a way to remove margin around an ion-card. It seems like the ionic framework suggested way to do this is by using global variables in a theme file, such as the default theme > variagles.scss

Using the suggested variables yields no change in margin:

```
$card-md-margin-left: 0;
$card-ios-margin-left: 0;
```

However, using the ion-card tag instead works:

```
ion-card {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a change in ionic3 vs ionic4, but I'm having a hard time finding any ionic4 related documentation about theme variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you viewing the changes VIA the ionic serve command in your web browser?

the MD and IOS style tags you reference, are specific to the ANDROID/IOS platforms, so you are not likely seeing these in the web browser for that very reason.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct. Is the preferred method for overriding in the browser view then to use the css selector as I have done? Also, is it safe to assume then that the $card-ios-margin-left and $card-md-margin-left would override the css selector method when viewing on andriod or IOS?

Comment: @DustinDuPree It's best to test it out on an Emulator to be sure.. using xcode for iOS and Android Studio for Android. Unless you require to do unique styles based on the platform, which it looks like you don't, then you are safe to use the style without the SASS variables in your 2nd example. That should work on all platforms.